# How can I solve "Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request,"?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

My code like this :

```
public function functionA(Request $request)
{
    ...
    if($request->get('data')) {
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($request->get('data'));echo '</pre>';die();
        $data = json_decode($request->get('data'), true);
        $data = collect($data['data']);
        $this->validate($data, [
            'id'=>'required|numeric',
            'quantity'=>'required|numeric',
        ]);
        $input = $data->only('id', 'quantity','request_date');
        ...
    }
}
```

The result of `echo '<pre>';print_r($request->get('data'));echo '</pre>';die();` like this :

> {"data":{"id":46,"quantity":1,"total":100000,"information":"chelsea","name":"Hazard","request_date":"14-08-2017
>   16:26:00"},"expired":"2017-08-14T06:27:00.738Z"}

If the code executed, there exist error like this :

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\Request,...

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter passed to `validate` should be an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

So you need to pass the `$request` object to `validate` method as the first parameter like this

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'validation' => 'rules',
]);
```

If you are receiving input as JSON make sure  `Content-Type` header of the request is set to `application/json`

jQuery ajax example

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'id': 'value', 
        'quantity': 'value'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json'
});
```

Comment: I had do it. `$data = $request`

Comment: @SuccessMan Looking at the code you posted `$data` is a collection.

Comment: I'm still confused. Can you update your answer in more detail?

Comment: Is it still throw the error after changing the parameter passed to `validate` from `$data` to `$request`

Comment: No error. But the validation not display. This : `If you are receiving input as JSON make sure  Content-Type header of the request is set to application/json`. How can I set it?

Comment: The errors doesn't display because you have wrapped the actual input values inside `data`. I guess if you change your rule to `'data.data.id' => 'required|numeric'` you should see some feedback. How do you send the request to server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151868/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-success-man).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `use Request;` in your controller, then replace it with,

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: I had use it. But It's the same